# Data comparison with specific row and column

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, point

I have a set of data with 10000 rows and 10 columns in a text file. Here are some samples-

```
#      x1       y1       x2       y2       x3       y3       x4       y4      Area
1   0.0000   0.0000   0.8147   0.0000   0.8147   0.1355   0.0000   0.1355   0.1104
2   0.8147   0.0000   1.0000   0.0000   1.0000   0.1355   0.8147   0.1355   0.0251
3   0.8147   0.1355   0.9058   0.1355   0.9058   0.8350   0.8147   0.8350   0.0637
4   0.0000   0.1355   0.8147   0.1355   0.8147   1.0000   0.0000   1.0000   0.7043
5   0.9058   0.1355   1.0000   0.1355   1.0000   0.8350   0.9058   0.8350   0.0659
6   0.9058   0.8350   1.0000   0.8350   1.0000   1.0000   0.9058   1.0000   0.0155
7   0.8147   0.8350   0.9058   0.8350   0.9058   1.0000   0.8147   1.0000   0.0150
```

I would like to check these points using this program-

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>
    using namespace std;

    double CheckPoint(){
        double slope, intercept,A, B, C, D,px, py,left, top, right, bottom,dx, dy;

        cin >> A; // take from  column
        cin >> B; // take from  column
        cin >> C; // take from column
        cin >> D; // take from  column
        cin >> px; // take value from other rows and column and check
        cin >> py; // take value from other rows and column and check

        dx = C - A;
        dy = D - B;
        slope = dy / dx;

        // y = mx + c
        // intercept c = y - mx
        intercept = B - slope * A; // which is same as D - slope * C

        // For Bounding Box
        if(A < C)
        {
            left = A;
            right = C;
        }
        else
        {
            left = C;
            right = A;
        }
        if(B < D)
        {
            top = B;
            bottom = D;
        }
        else
        {
            top = B;
            bottom = D;
        }

        if( slope * px + intercept > (py - 0.01) &&
            slope * px + intercept < (py + 0.01))
        {
            if( px >= left && px <= right && 
                py >= top && py <= bottom )
            {
               // cout the numbers of common point and the line number
            }
            else
               // cout the numbers of common point and the line number
        }
        else
            // cout no common point;
    }

    int main()
    {
        cout<<CheckPoint();
        return 0;
    }
```

- First I want to

  - take the value of A from x1
  - take the value of B from y1
  - take the value of C from x2
  - take the value of D from y2
  - and check if they have any common point with x3, y3, x4 and y4. But it will not check the values from it's own row. This process will continue for other rows as well.
- Then I want to

  - take the value of A from x2
  - take the value of B from y2
  - take the value of C from x3
  - take the value of D from y3
  - and check if they have any common point with x1, y1, x4 and y4. And as stated above, it will not check the value of it's own row and also apply for the row2,row3 ....etc.

**Example on response to the comments**

When the program take A=0.0000   B=0.0000   C=0.8147   D=0.0000, It will not compare the values with x3=0.8147   y3=0.1355   x4=0.0000   y4=0.1355.i.e it will skip the row from which it takes the values of x1,y1,x2,y2.

Again when it takes the values of A,B,C,D from 2nd row, i.e 0.A=8147   B=0.0000   C=1.0000   D=0.0000, then it skip the values of x3,y3,x4,y4 in row 2.

I wanted it to count the number of matching point and return the number of line in which it found the point. How can I do it?

Comment: Are you asking how to read data from a text file?

Comment: yes, the data are in a text file.

Comment: yes, but are you asking how to read that data from the file? or something else? what's your question?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Read data from a specific column and row. And check data for specific column and row. Return the number of matching point and number of lines in which it find the matching points.

Comment: read all the data first, then, once everything is stored in the right data structures (vector?), then do the calculations.

Comment: 1. Search Stack Overflow for "[c++] read text file". 2. Search Stack Overflow for "[c++] line intersection".  Sorry, but there have been too many "how do I read from file" questions lately.

Comment: actually I see at least 6 questions here. voted to close.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I know how to read text file in c++. But I don't want to read the all data.

Comment: Reading in all the data first is faster than always seeking to individual records.  Otherwise, since you know how to read from a file, you know how to position the file pointer to a record or even to a field in the record (assuming the records are fixed length).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: But it will not check the all values at ones. When it takes the value of x1,y1,x2,y2 it will check the values with x3,y3,x4,y4 without checking it's own row. How can I specify that?

Comment: Do you need to read the values and save them while you check other rows?  How did you tell it to check (point)P1, P2, versus P3 and P4?  I'm confused.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Edited my question and add an example. Please check.

Comment: `if(B < D)
        {
            top = B;
            bottom = D;
        }
        else
        {
            top = B;
            bottom = D;
        }` <-- I think this is not what you meant to code.

Comment: What points in the file are compared with [X1,Y1] and [X2, Y2] from row 1?  Please explain what you **want** to do, refrain from stating what is is **not** going to do.

Comment: I can understand that my question become ambiguous. It would be better if I open a new post and elaborate about what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, this problem consists of reading pairs of numbers (x, y) from a list that also contains a few other things. So let's takle that first:

```
std::fstream fin("infile.txt");    // Adjust as needed. 


struct Point
{
   double x, y;
};

struct Line
{
   int lineNum; 
   Point pts[4]; 
   double area; 
}

Line ln; 

fin >> ln.lineNum;    // Read the line number. 
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
   fin >> line.pts[i].x >> line.pts[i].y; 
}
fin >> ln.area;
```

Now you can use the values in "line" to determine if it matches your conditions or not, and output the relevant information.

Comment: Thank you. I think I can use this. Voted up.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an answer but a clarification question to the O.P.

Assuming that the text file is a table of points for a 4 sided polygon and the area of the polygon.

Is first question is to find any intersections between line segment `[x1,y1,x2,y2]` and line segment `[x3, y3, x4, y4]`?

Do you want to check line segment `[x1,y1,x2,y2]` against points from other rows?

In any case, I suggest the following:

- Create a class Point, containing an X and Y value.
- Create a class Line that contains two Points:

`class Line

    {

      Point begin;

      Point end;

    };`

- Create a class called Polygon with 4 points and an area:

`class Polygon

    {

      Point point_container[4];

      double area;

    };`

- Read in the file into a `std::vector<Polygon>`.
- Determine your algorithm in terms of points, lines and polygons.
  **Think in terms of polygons, points and line (segments).**

Hopefully this should clear up the confusion.  I suggest making a new post and speak in terms of points and polygons.

Comment: Yes, these are the points of polygons. I understand this become ambiguous.I will open a new post. Thank you.